# AWS iOS Swift 3 Cognito Type does not conform to protocol

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, swift3, aws-mobilehub

Hi im using AWS Mobile hub in iOS i followed the introductions to aut with cognito. It says I have to import the user pool files from the sample. I did so, but this throws me an error:

```
extension SignInViewController: AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication {

    func getDetails(_ authenticationInput: AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationInput, passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource: AWSTaskCompletionSource<AnyObject>) {
        self.passwordAuthenticationCompletion = passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource
    }

    func didCompleteStepWithError(_ error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                UIAlertView(title: "ERROR",
                    message: error.localizedDescription,
                    delegate: nil,
                    cancelButtonTitle: "Ok").show()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Errors:

> Type 'SignInViewController' does not conform to protocol
>   'AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication'

Also:

> Protocol requires function
>   'getDetails(_:passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource:)' with type
>   '(AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationInput,
>   AWSTaskCompletionSource)
>   -> Void'; do you want to add a stub? (AWSCognitoIdentityProvider.AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication)

and:

> Candidate has non-matching type
>   '(AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationInput,
>   AWSTaskCompletionSource) -> ()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Protocols/AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication.html), any class conforming to `AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthentication` should implement :

```
– getPasswordAuthenticationDetails:passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource
– didCompletePasswordAuthenticationStepWithError
```

You don't implement them, hence the error.

**EDIT**
Yes, you're right, the function signatures changed in Swift 3 (see [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/473)).

They should be like this :

```
func getDetails(_ authenticationInput: AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationInput, passwordAuthenticationCompletionSource: AWSTaskCompletionSource<AWSCognitoIdentityPasswordAuthenticationDetails>)
func didCompleteStepWithError(_ error: Error?)
```

Looks like your version of the first func is slightly different.

Comment: They are implemented, just renamed in Swift 3